# SLO monitor tags always in lowercase

Tags: tags, monitor, datadog

I am using datadog to create my SLO monitor. I am creating a monitor-type SLO monitor. I gave a tag in uppercase let's consider it **TAG**. But, when I save and exit it shows **tag** instead of **TAG**.

Can anybody please let me know how to get an uppercase tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Per the docs, "Tags are converted to lowercase."

https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/tagging/#defining-tags